# How to navigate to another screen using DrawerItem

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Im stuck with navigation in Navigation Drawer
my partner did this part of the code and he added DrawerItem(Which will be seen to every user(Admin/client)

i cant figure out how to navigate with it. i tried navigation.navigate("") and its not working

```
          <DrawerItem 
        label="הגדרות"
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0,
          left: 0,
          marginBottom: 60,
          borderTopColor: "#afafaf",
          borderTopWidth: 3,
        }}
        onPress={() => logOut()} //Here i need to navigate to the page "aboutUs"
        icon={({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialIcons name="settings" color={color} size={size} />
        )}
      />
```

About us stack screen:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const aboutStack = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName={"Aboutus"}
      screenOptions={{
        headerLeft: () => (
          <SimpleLineIcons
            name="menu"
            style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}
            size={24}
            color="black"
            onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
          />
        ),
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="קצת עלינו"
        component={Aboutus}
        options={{ headerTitleAlign: "center" }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default aboutStack;
```

Comment: Where is the aboutUs screen ? can you provide the details of the stack

Comment: Do you need the aboutUs Stack screen?

Comment: I need to see how your navigation stack is arranged, like the stacks and the drawer navigator

Comment: added the stack screen

Comment: So you have a stack inside a drawer navigator, no errors when using navigation.navigate right ?

Comment: Well i do have errors using it, maybe im not using it right. 
Just to mention, when i use drawer.screen its working good

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222773/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-osher-revach).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the props that are passed to the custom drawer and navigate using the name of the screen like below.

```
onPress={() => props.navigaton.navigate("קצת עלינו")}
```